# Camera View never shows up

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

using firemonkey, I have a few cubes inside a `viewport3d` along with a camera and a light.

I have a  few trackbars, a set for controlling the position and a set for controlling the angle and a label for each to get back  the camera's location.

The problem is when i move the trackbars, the camera's x,y,z updates but never moves the screen.

```
    procedure TForm2.TrackBar_PositionChange(Sender: TObject);
  begin
      Camera1.Position.X := TrackBar_PositionX.Value;
      Camera1.Position.Y := TrackBar_PositionY.Value;
      Camera1.Position.Z := TrackBar_PositionZ.Value;
    { Updating the displayed values of the coordinates }
    Label_Position.Text := Format('X: %d, Y: %d, Z: %d',
      [Round(Camera1.Position.X), Round(Camera1.Position.Y),
      Round(Camera1.Position.Z)]);
  end;


procedure TForm2.TrackBar_RotationAngleChange(Sender: TObject);
  begin
      Camera1.RotationAngle.X := TrackBar_RotationAngleX.Value;
      Camera1.RotationAngle.Y := TrackBar_RotationAngleY.Value;
      Camera1.RotationAngle.Z := TrackBar_RotationAngleZ.Value;
    { Updating the displayed values of the coordinates  }
    Label_RotationAngle.Text := Format('X: %d, Y: %d, Z: %d',
      [Round(Camera1.RotationAngle.X), Round(Camera1.RotationAngle.Y),
      Round(Camera1.RotationAngle.Z)]);
  end;
```

any idea what i am missing... also i have set in object inspector , viewport3d camera to camera 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to uncheck the "UsingDesignCamera" in the Viewport3d Object Inspector.